# C# - How can I check if a Type is concrete?

Tags: c#, types

I have a collection of Types and I want to filter out every Type that is not concrete.

I can see that I can check isAbstract and isInterface to catch most non-concretes, but is this going to miss anything?

Is there an "isConcrete" property?

Comment: Anything that is not abstract or an interface is concrete. This is not to say you can necessarily instantiate it,

Comment: `IsAbstract` catches interfaces too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess that if you give a `IsClass && !IsAbstract` a try this could work?

```
if isConcreteType(myType) { DoSomething(); }

bool isConcreteType(Type type) { 
    return type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsInterface;
}
```

As per comment by [**KC-NH**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3930102/kc-nh):

> ***Structs*** are value types and so **IsClass** will be **false**. Do you want structs to be considered concrete classes? If so, remove the IsClass condition

So if you want to consider a [**struct**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx) a concrete type, you have to wave away the `IsClass` constraint.

```
bool isConcreteType(Type type) { return !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsInterfaces; }
```

Comment: Structs are value types and so IsClass will be false.  Do you want structs to be considered concrete classes?  If so, remove the IsClass condition.

Comment: Worth noting for anyone stumbling across this after so many eons:

`isConcreteType(typeof(List<>))` will pass, despite this (very likely) not being part of the passing test cases OP had in mind.

Based on the above, I believe `!type.IsGenericTypeDefinition && !type.IsGenericParameter` should be added to the conditions.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of IsAbstract is "is concrete", so you're good with those checks

Comment: Could be an interface.

Comment: @Haney: `IsAbstract` returns `true` for interfaces too I think.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I think you're right. Just tested it on `System.Collections.IEnumerable` and was `true`